# How to get the whole row for a if specific column has a certain text with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to filter my excel spreadsheet for the word "GHH" anywhere in the text of a cell in a specific column. I have managed to do this by I then need to have returned the whole row that this text is found in. This I can't do as there doesnt seem to be a way of using the `getRowIndex` method to then display the whole row.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator < Row > rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator < Cell > cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
            if (cell.toString().contains("GHH")) {
                String key = cell.getStringCellValue();
                int RI = cell.getRowIndex();
            }
        }
    }
    workBook.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a `List<HSSFRow>` to save filtered rows as bellow:

```
List<HSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<HSSFRow>();
Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
while (rows.hasNext ()){
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next ();  
 Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator (); 
 while (cells.hasNext ()){
    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next (); 
    if (cell.toString().contains("GHH")) {
        String key = cell.getStringCellValue();
        int RI=cell.getRowIndex();
        filteredRows.add(row);
        break;
    }
}
// then use filteredRows
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have two bits of logic, one for handling a "matched" row, one for matching. Something like:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

public void matchingRow(Row row) {
   System.out.println("Row " + (row.getRowNum()+1) + " matched:");
   for (Cell c : row) {
      System.out.println("   " + formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
   }
}
public void handleFile(File excel) throws Exception {
   Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(excel);
   Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
   for (Row row : sheet) {
      boolean matched = false;
      for (Cell cell : row) {
         if (matched) continue;
         if (formatter.formatCellValue(cell).contains("GHH")) {
            matchingRow(row);
            matched = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

That will check every cell in the first sheet, and if the text of a cell in a row matches `GHH` will then print out the row's contents. If a row has that in twice, it'll only print it once