# How to modify parameters for testing using excel or other approach?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I would like to separate the testing parameters from the testing script to achieve data-driven automation testing. I have to be under java 1.6 environment so I cannot utilize testNG which requires java 1.7+. Therefore, I need to use some workaround like apache-poi to read excel files and configure parameters for achieving my goal.

I cannot quite understand how to get the row of value in column A from xls which has been switched on as "1" on B column or other notion to be the testing parameter in-use. I don't know if apache-poi is supposed to be doing such job as I have done my research in this community but seem no one is using it in such way.

```
 |  A  | B
1| ABC | 1
2| DEF | 0
3| GHI | 0
4| JKL | 0
```

1 and 0 from B column could be other expression of booleans and could be multiple positive results but the idea is to list out all the parameter options and switch them on or off for use in the testing script. Just like in the sql idea of Select A from table where B = 1. But I can only get the value "1" instead of "ABC" during my use.

The script would be getStringCellValue or something with the value content of "ABC" as the parameter for running the test instead of putting "ABC" straight inside the script and change it/them every time when we need to use different parameters.

btw could there be other way of using sql syntax and get the value from a file? I'm not bonded with using xls or not. But .xml parameters using testNG is not feasible for me because I need to be in the java 1.6 environment as mentioned.

Thanks for reading.

UPDATE:

```
    HSSFSheet hspsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    List<HSSFRow> filteredhspRows = new ArrayList<HSSFRow>();
    Iterator<Row> hspritr = hspsheet.iterator();
    while (hspritr.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow rows = (HSSFRow) hspritr.next();
    Iterator<Cell> hspcitr = rows.cellIterator();
    while (hspcitr.hasNext())
    {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) hspcitr.next();
        if (cell.toString().contains("T")) 
        {
            filteredhspRows.add(rows);
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
    }
```

By using the above codes, I am only being able to get the cells containing "T" but not only getting the value in Column A when its corresponding value (same row) in Column B is "T".

Comment: `But I can only get the value "1" instead of "ABC" during my use`. I think you have a bit problem with the use of `Apache Poi`, please share the code how you read the excel file.

Comment: Sorry but I have discarded the codes since they're not working and I cannot revert back as I have used many other approaches to write the codes. But I remember I was borrowing from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050282/how-to-get-the-whole-row-for-a-if-specific-column-has-a-certain-text-with-poi

Comment: Maybe this is can be the clue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57312482/how-to-handle-different-users-in-different-environments/57323547#57323547

Comment: I did reference to the article but I am kind of digesting it so I am now trying different codings. I have made some update to my question that I managed to recreate the codes I have mentioned. Perhaps u could find sth in it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no SQL-syntax while accessing a spreadsheet via Apache POI.

If I understood correctly you are more or less interested in the values of A, where B has value 1.

You could use the following code to find out all the relevant A-values by simply iterating over the rows of the sheet:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
Collection<String> relevantValuesFromA = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Cell bCellOfRow = row.getCell(1);
    if ("1".equals(bCellOfRow.getStringCellValue())) {
        relevantValuesFromA.add(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
    }
}

//now you can use relevantValuesFromA for your tests
```

Comment: Thank you it did show the correct results. However, how do I chop the collection into a brunch of string value?

Comment: What do you mean with 'chop into a brunch of string value'? Maybe [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) has methods you need...

Comment: I mean that the current result would be a group of values instead of multiple individual values, is it possible to specifically identify each of them?
Like [ABC, DEF] into "ABC" "DEF" and I can use them individually.
This is another question tho thanks for your solution.

Comment: nvm i found this article https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-convert-list-to-string-comma-separated
going to start a new thread when needed, thanks for solving my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is for get cell value only in first row.

Remove the condition : `if (cell.toString().contains("T"))` and remove state `break;`

```
Iterator<Cell> hspcitr = rows.cellIterator();
while (hspcitr.hasNext())
{
    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) hspcitr.next();
    filteredhspRows.add(rows);
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
}
```

But if you want get all cell each row, use :

```
while (hspritr.hasNext ()){
    HSSFRow rows = (HSSFRow) hspritr.next();
    Iterator<Cell> hspcitr = rows.cellIterator();
    while (hspcitr.hasNext())
    {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) hspcitr.next();
        filteredhspRows.add(rows);
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
}
```